# Mensaje de espera mientras se genera archivo de excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, excel, datagridview

Me gustaria agregar un mensaje de espera y que el cursor cambie al de cargar mientras mi programa genera un archivo en excel ya que es como muy grande la cantidad de datos suele tardar pero nose que codigo poner y en que parte,que deberia hacer?

```
//Metodo de excel
private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
{
    SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
    fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
    if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
        aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
        hoja_trabajo =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
        for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
                }
            }
        }
        libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        libros_trabajo.Close(true);
        //Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//cambia el tipo de cursor al tipo wait
        aplicacion.Quit();
       // Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//restaura el tipo de cursor de defecto
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mostrar un mensaje de espera vas a tener que lanzar el proceso de generacion del excel en un `thread` separado para que no bloquee el de la UI

Para hacerlo simple podrias usar el componente `BackgroundWorker`

[Información general sobre el componente BackgroundWorker](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/backgroundworker-component-overview)

La idea es que definas el evento `DoWork` poniendo el proceso de generacion del excel alli dentro, pero vas a tener que sacar fuera el `SaveFileDialog` ya que este es un componente parte de la UI

Tampoco vas a poder acceder directo al `DataGridView` porque tambien es parte de la UI, debes generar el excel en base a los datos, pero para eso podrias volcarlos a un `DataTable`

Algo como ser:

```
private string fileName;
private DataTable datos;
private FormEspera form1;

public void button1_Click(...)
{
    SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
    fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
    if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        form1 = new FormEspera();
        form1.Show();

        fileName = fichero.FileName;
        datos = (DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource;
        BackGroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    ExportarDataGridViewExcel(fileName, datos);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{  
    form1.Close();
}


private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(string fileName, DataTable dt)
{

    var aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
    var hoja_trabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            //aqui adaptarlo al uso del DataTable
        }
    }

    libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fileName,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
    libros_trabajo.Close(true);
    aplicacion.Quit();


}
```

La idea es que definas un form que muestres al usuario para la espera, en este caso lo llame `FormEspera`, pero puedes ponerlo cualquier otro nombre, entonces lo instancias y muestras antes de lanzar el proceso en segundo plano

Cuando el proceso termina se ejecuta el `RunWorkerCompleted` y cierras el form

Comment: No me aparecio el FormEspera